# Using AWSGlue as Hive Metastore where data is in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue

apologies if this has been answered elsewhere (but I don't think it has). I'm trying to use AWSGlue as an external metastore for Hive via an EMR cluster.

I have some data stored as text files on S3, and via the AWSGlue web console I created a table definition over those text files.

I also started up an EMR cluster following directions here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-hive-metastore-glue.html

When I ssh into my EMR cluster and try to access Hive, I was expecting to find that the table I created in AWSGlue would exist when I ran a "show tables" command, but instead I get the following error message when starting the interactive Hive shell:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:                                                                                                                                            org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: MetaException(message:Unable to verify existence of default database: com.amazona                                                                                                                                           ws.services.glue.model.AccessDeniedException: Please migrate your Catalog to enable access to this database (Service: AWSGlue; Statu                                                                                                                                           s Code: 400; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID: e6b2a87b-fe5a-11e8-8ed4-5d1e42734679))

It seems like there's some permission error involved here.  I'm using EMR_EC2_DefaultRole for my EC2 Instance Profile, so I didn't think this would happen.

Am I missing something obvious?

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Comment: did u manage to solve this? I am facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Kindly attach AWS GLUE and S3 full access to you current IAM Role. that should do it.

Comment: Thanks, but I believe EMR_EC2_DefaultRole already has full access to both Glue and S3 (I just double-checked).

Answer (score 0):

In order to solve this issue, you will have to migrate your existing Athena catalog to Glue Data Catalog as explained [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-upgrade.html)

To confirm your Athena catalog has been migrated, execute the following commands using the AWS cli:

```
aws glue get-catalog-import-status --catalog-id <aws-account-id> --region <region>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information--but in my situation, I don't have an Athena catalog.  I just have a text file stored in S3.  I created a table definition in the Glue Data Catalog, and am trying to get this table to show up in Hive when I start a new cluster.

Comment: Yes I understood you are not using Athena Catalog but by default it will be pointed to Athena data catalog.Can you follow the procedure as mentioned in the link in answer and see if you are able to run "show tables".Even after following the procedure if it's till not working then run this command and post the output. 
    aws glue get-catalog-import-status --catalog-id <acc-id>

Answer (score 0):

I have faced exactly same issue recently and able to get over it by upgrading Athena to Glue Catalog.

I am also not using Athena or Redshift Spectrum to query the table but on Glue and Athena consoles there was a message saying:

> To use the AWS Glue Data Catalog as a common metadata repository for Amazon Athena, Amazon Redshift Spectrum, and Amazon EMR, you need to upgrade your Athena Data Catalog to the AWS Glue Data Catalog. Without the upgrade, tables and partitions created by AWS Glue cannot be queried with Amazon Athena or Redshift Spectrum.

Soon after upgrading I was able to query the table through hive and spark shells from EMR cluster.

This might be because your `default` and other databases are already created via Athena before and should be upgraded to Glue to be used from EMR as `default` is the default database that your hive will use after going to hive in EMR. You have to use `DBName.tableName` or explicitly switch to the DB that consists of your table to run queries.